# Пробелы в пути к файлу

Tags: c#

Надо проверить установлена ли на компьютерах из списка определенная версия 1C
Проблема в том что по умолчанию она устанавливается по пути: `\\computername\c$\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\8.3.18.1208`. А c# не воспринимает пробелы в пути.

Пытался брать строку в кавычки:

```
string path = "\"\\\\" + computer + "\\c$\\Program Files (x86)\\1cv8\\8.3.18.1208\"";
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
    }
```

Но он все равно отказывается ее воспринимать. Подскажите решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно путь оборачивать в кавычки.

Вот так у меня работает. 1С-ку нужной версии на машине не имею, доступа к другим машинам тоже, поэтому вот такой урезанный пример покажу.

```cs
string computer = Environment.MachineName;
string path = $@"\\{computer}\c$\Program Files (x86)\";
Console.WriteLine(Directory.Exists(path));
```

Вывод в консоль

```
True
```

Как видите, с пробелами проблем нет. Все что вам нужно, это сетевой доступ к дискам `c$` на удаленных машинах и их имена.